# ngFor on array after loading

Tags: angular, ngfor

I'm trying to make a cards list after an array is loaded. See my code below.

```js
 locations;

  constructor(
    private toolbarTitle: ToolbarTitleService,
    public popoverController: PopoverController,
    private syncService: SyncServiceService,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {}

  async ngOnInit() {
    this.toolbarTitle.setToolbarTitle('Locaties');
    const user = await this.userService.getUser();
    // Get all the shops
    this.locations = await this.syncService.getShops(user);
  }
```

html

```html
        <ion-card
          *ngFor="let location of locations | async"
          class="locatieCard"
        >
          <ion-item>
            <img class="locatieImg" src="assets/spar_img.jpg" slot="start" />
            <ion-grid>
              <ion-row>
                <ion-card-subtitle>{{ location.Name }}</ion-card-subtitle>
              </ion-row>
              <ion-row>
                <ion-button
                  size="small"
                  fill="clear"
                  (click)="presentPopover($event)"
                  >Meer info</ion-button
                >
              </ion-row>
            </ion-grid>
          </ion-item>
        </ion-card>
```

But it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?
I've already used async in my ngFor directive, but that didn't solve it for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may have confused observables and Promises. What type does your `getShops()` method return?

If it returns an `Observable<Location[]>` then you don't need the `await` as an `await` would wait for a Promise to resolve.

If it returns a `Promise<Location[]>` then you need the `await` but not the `async` pipe in your `ngFor`. The `| async` actually subscribes to an observable.

**EDIT:**
The actual solution is in the discussion/chat below.

Comment: The return value of my getShops() is actually undefined. 
`getShops(user: any) {
    const selector = {
      _id: { $in: user.Shops },
    };
    this.dbService.localDB
      .find({
        selector,
      })
      .then((result: any) => {
        console.log('SHOPS: ', result);
        return result;
      });
  }`
Am I doing something wrong with the _return_?

Comment: Ok that's a Promise you get from the localDB. so the solution for you should be to remove the `| async` from the template.

Comment: "locations" (right above the constructor) stays undefined when I try to check what's in it.
`this.locations = await this.syncService.getShops(user);` Might be doing something wrong here

Comment: does this line log any data? `console.log('SHOPS: ', result);` or do you get any error messages?

Comment: It does. Gives me a docs file with an array of all the shops

Comment: ok. I think I found it. you need to add a `return` in front of  `this.dbService.localDB.find(...)` to actually return the promise from your top level.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/231473/discussion-between-david-b-and-furkan-ozturk).